# Quickblox one to one chat history not working

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using Javascript SDK for 1-1 chat in Quickblox, but somehow I am not able to store the chat history.

I am following this [link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/1:1_Chat_history#Techical_integration_.28send_message.29).

```
var message = {
    body: text,
    type: 'chat',
    extension: {
        nick: chatUser.email,
        // token from session is set on window object
        token: window.token,
        // MyChat is a custom class_name
        class_name: 'MyChat'

    }
};
```

I am passing the `class_name` and `token` since I saw the android sdk following the same pattern.

```
private Message createMsgWithAdditionalInfo(int userId, String body,     Map<?, ?> addinfoParams){
    Message message = new Message(QBChatUtils.getChatLoginFull(userId), Message.Type.chat);
    String addInfo = ToStringHelper.toString(addinfoParams, "",  Consts.ESCAPED_AMPERSAND);
//
    MessageExtension messageExtension = new MessageExtension(Consts.QB_INFO, "");
    try {
        messageExtension.setValue("token", QBAuth.getBaseService().getToken());
        messageExtension.setValue("class_name", "ChatMessage");
        messageExtension.setValue("additional", addInfo);
    } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    message.addExtension(messageExtension);
    message.setBody(body);
       return message;
    }
```

Also in instructions I see this.

```
<message id="123" type="chat" to="291-92@chat.quickblox.com" from="292-92@chat.quickblox.com"><body>Hi there</body><quickblox xmlns=""><token>848d4bf336d99532deff6bf7c8bb4b7e7b1a71f9</token><class_name>ChatMessage</class_name></quickblox></message>
```

Here also I see `token` & `class` passed so I am guessing how to I structure in my `message` object so that I get it to work.

The way I have created chatService is this.

```
chatService = new QBChat(params);
// to send message I am using sendMessage function 
// message object is same as defined above.
chatService.sendMessage(recipientID, message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old and deprecated method to store chat history

Look at this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Server-side_chat_history

```
  var msg = {
    body: "Hey",
    extension: {
      save_to_history: 1
    },
    senderId: currentUser.id, 
  };
```

You have to use 'save_to_history' to store a message

You can use this branch as a basis
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/tree/develop.chat/samples/chat

Comment: Thanks I figured that out your answer is the correct solution for someone who is stuck with the same problem.